# 2 docker builds into a multi-build

Tags: docker

I have 1 dockerfile, 1 stage of the build for the node server, serving some data, and the 2nd stage is a react app. I use a docker compose file to run the dockerfile.

I am able to access the react app via port 3000, but the 2nd stage server isn't running so I can't access the data.

Any idea how to solve it?

```
FROM node:12.6

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 5500 // node server

CMD ["npm","run", "server"]


FROM node:12.6

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm i

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3000 // react app

CMD ["npm","run", "dev"]
```

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  testingapp:
    container_name: testingApp
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src:delegated
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

I have read various docs online.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to run the front- and back-ends in the same container.  A container only runs one process, though; if you need two separate processes from the same code base then you can run two separate containers off the same image, overriding the `command:` on one of them.

So reduce the Dockerfile to copy the code base in, and declare one process or the other as the main container command:

```bash
FROM node:12.6
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY ./ ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "server"]
```

Now in your Compose file, declare two separate containers.  For the second, override the `command:` with the alternate program to run.  Both can `build:` the same image; the second build will come entirely from the Docker layer cache and be all but free.  The code is built into the image and you don't need to replace it using `volumes:`.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  express:
    build: .
    ports: ['5500:3000']
  react:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    ports: ['3000:3000']
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to work. It looks like http://localhost:5500/ isn't up? I have mirrored your above suggestion.

Comment: have solved with 2 dockerfiles